# "with submission"

Tags: meaning

> Hamilton quickly focused on the last part of his opponent’s argument as support for his attempt to
>   introduce evidence of the truthfulness of his client’s publications. Hamilton offered the following
>   brilliantly ironic response:
>
> > Well, suppose it were so, and let us agree for once that truth is a greater sin than falsehood:
> >     Yet as the offenses are not equal, and as the punishment is arbitrary, that is, according as the
> >     judges in their discretion shall direct to be inflicted; is it not absolutely necessary that they
> >     should know whether the libel is true or false, that they may by that means be able to proportion
> >     the punishment? For would it not be a sad case if the judges, for want of a due information,
> >     should chance to give as severe a judgment against a man for writing or publishing a lie as for
> >     writing or publishing a truth? And yet this (**with  submission**), as monstrous and ridiculous as it
> >     may seem to be, is the natural consequence of Mr. Attorney’s doctrine that truth makes a worse
> >     libel than falsehood, and must follow from his not proving our papers to be false, or not
> >     suffering us to prove them to be true.

Woudl someone please explain and elucidate **with  submission**? I guess its meaning to be the following, yet I still don't apprehend it:

[2.2. [count noun] [*Law*]  A proposition or argument presented by counsel to a judge or jury](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/submission?q=submission).

Source: P38, *America on Trial* by Alan Dershowitz

Answer (score 2):

More in the sense of humility. Today one would likely say "with all due respect" or "with respect to my learned opponent."